# How to summurize atop raw data?

Tags: system-monitoring

My client wanted to know how much of his VPS resources are being used. As this is a managed VPS the admin installed `atop` and gave me the permissions to read the log files.

I look at them and didn't got any overall picture as I was scrolling all the way through each single second (or at least the first few seconds of the first minute of the log). I spend some time in [reading](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop) the `atop` manual but didn't really got how I can get something like data summary (when was the pick of CPU and MEM usage, for how long and so on).

The only thing i succeed was to convert the raw file into txt but still doesn't know what to do next (I was thinking of using some excel macros to summarize the data but this is huge thing)

So my actual questions are two?

1. Can I (or the sys admin) change the configuration of `atop` for the interval of the records, instead every second to every 60 seconds ( I know that I can use the interactive mode like `atop -w /tmp/atop28.raw 60 168` but I think that after I close the ssh connection it will terminate automatically)?
2. Is there a command that can sum up the things or at least shows less records by given interval (something like `atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20150827.1 -b 00:01 -e 23:59` but with one more parameter - interval of 60 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this solve your problem, then you can use screen or tmux so run your command even you detach the terminal.

> Can I (or the sys admin) change the configuration of atop for the interval of the records, instead every second to every 60 seconds ( I know that I can use the interactive mode like atop -w /tmp/atop28.raw 60 168 but I think that after I close the ssh connection it will terminate automatically)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to see what i can make with screen. Thanks.